# Scanf ignoring new line character when scanning from input file

Tags: c, input, newline, scanf

I'm working on a program that intends to read multiple lines of strings and sort them into arrays of strings.

I'm trying to read the first line manually and the loop is supposed to exit once it reads the new line character '\n'. This works when I manually enter the strings in terminal, but reading from in input file (through terminal), it does not read the newline character and the loop continues.

```
char array[20][20];
char letter = 'a';
for (int i = 0; letter != '\n'; i++) {
    scanf("%s",array[i]);    //store the word into an array of words
    printf("Scanned %s\n",array[i]);
    scanf("%c",&letter);     //look for space or new line character
}
```

It works when I manually enter this text, but not when reading it from a file:

```
word word1 word2
word3 word4 word5
```

When inputting manually, I would enter the first line, "word word1 word2", hit enter, and it would scan that line and end the program.

When using the file, it returns:

```
$ ./potw18 < input.txt
Scanned word
Scanned word1
Scanned word2
Scanned word3
Scanned word4
Scanned word5
Scanned
Scanned ▒
Scanned
Scanned ▒
Scanned
Scanned ▒8.▒
Scanned
Scanned ▒8.▒
Scanned
```

And continues on.

Comment: Could you please post the definition of `array` here?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] along with a sample text file

Comment: Updated the OP with example and array definition.

Comment: Post the output of `cat input.txt`. BTW, post a _small_ _compilable_ program that reproduces the issue.

Comment: try `letter != '\n' && letter != '\r'`

Comment: "I'm trying to read the first line manually" --> use `fgets()` to read a _line_ of user input.  That function is designed for that.  `scanf()` is a general purpose scanning function and does not read a _line_ well.

Comment: @EricP, could you please post more code around the loop? What I want to know is that is it stopping after the first line atleast? Have you enclosed this in another loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just read each line with [`fgets(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets), until it returns `NULL`, which indicates a line was not read. You could also use [`getline(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdelim.3.html) to do this, which is a POSIX C function designed for reading lines efficiently. In terms of getting each words, you can use [`strtok(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) or [`strchr(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html) to parse each word at each space on the line, and safely add it to your 2d char array. Using `scanf()` only makes it harder to do this, as justified thoroughly in @Michael Burr's post.

Here is a basic example of reading lines from a file with `stdin`, and storing the found words in an array of strings:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUMWORDS 20
#define WORDLEN 20
#define LINESIZE 100

#define WORDSIZE(x) (sizeof x[0])
#define ARRSIZE(x) (sizeof x / sizeof x[0])

int main(void) {
    char array[NUMWORDS][WORDLEN];
    char line[LINESIZE];
    char *word = NULL, *currline = NULL;
    const char *delim = " \n";
    size_t numwords = 0;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL) {
        currline = line;

        word = strtok(currline, delim);
        while (word != NULL) {
            if (numwords < ARRSIZE(array) && strlen(word) < WORDSIZE(array)) {
                strcpy(array[numwords], word);
                numwords++;
            }
            word = strtok(NULL, delim);
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < numwords; i++) {
        printf("array[%zu] = %s\n", i, array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Note** The above code uses `strtok()`m which is a string function that you have to be careful with. It might be better to use `strchr()` here.

Answer (score 2):

I predict that the file `input.txt` has:

- whitespace (other than a newline) at the end of the first line, and
- is similar or simply doesn't have a newline at the end of the second line

Because of the first point, the `scanf("%c",&letter);` reads something other than a newline (a space, for example) so the program continues on to the second line.

After reading the last word, there's nothing in the file for `scanf()` to read, so it returns an error - every time that it's called.  The program doesn't check for those errors and blindly trudges on.

Personally, I'm not a huge fan of using `scanf()` except for quick-n-dirty one off code. It's too error prone for arbitrary input. I'd suggest reading lines into a buffer then using `sscanf()`, `strtok()` or something even better to parse from there (basically, similar to what @RoadRunner's answer says).

Comment: This is a good theory, but I've double checked the input file and there is no whitespace other than the newline between the first and second line.

Answer (score 0):

Use `scanf` to scan for a character and test to see if the character is whitespace using `isspace`. `break` when the character is newline.
If the character is not whitespace, use `ungetc` to replace the character into the input stream and then `scanf` the word. `%19s` prevents scanning too many characters into the array.

```
#include <ctype.h> //header for isspace

while ( scanf ( "%c", &letter) == 1) {
    if ( isspace ( letter)) {
        if ( letter == '\n') {
            break;
        }
    }
    else {
        ungetc ( letter, stdin);//replace letter in input stream
        if ( scanf ( "%19s", array[i]) == 1)
        {
            i++;
            if ( i >= 20) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
char array[20][20];
char letter = 'a';
for (int i = 0; letter != '\n'; i++) {
   gets(array);    //store the word into an array of words
   letter = array[i];
   scanf("%c",&letter);    
}
```

By using `gets` it should work.

Comment: `gets(array);` is the wrong usage of the now obsolete  function `gets()`.  That function has been removed from C since C11 and should not be used for new code for the last 6 years.

Comment: 'letter = array[i];', I don't think this makes sense. Also gets (even though obsolete) will read the entire line. He will have to separate at spaces.